# Typescript, class type is not assignable to index interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a class that has some public properties and I would like to pass it to a function with a generic argument of an index interface type, but I get an compiler error that says `Argument of type 'Car' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [k: string]: unknown; }'.`

Could someone explain what is wrong because I assume all Classes are of type object?!!

```js
class Car {

  name: string | undefined;

}

function toStr <T extends { [k: string]: unknown }>(i: T) {
  return i.toString();
}


const jeep = new Car();
jeep.name = 'jeep';

toStr(jeep);
```

Comment: `Car` doesn't define index signature but function parameter has constraint for it. Could you explain what's the point of generics here? Both `function toStr(i: object) ...` and `function toStr(i: Record<string, any>) ...` will work

Comment: Or accept any type with a toString method (should be everything) toStr(i: {toString(): string}): string

Comment: @LindaPaiste technically not everything will have `toString` (e.g. `Object.create(null)`), but typescript can't catch this

Comment: The point is `eslint` complains when you use the `object` type.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `object` instead `{ [k: string]: unknown }`.

```js
class Car {

  name: string | undefined;

}

function toStr <T extends object>(i: T) {
  return i.toString();
}


const jeep = new Car();
jeep.name = 'jeep';

const result = toStr(jeep);
```